# Portable code for printing size_t values?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm working with a snippet of C code that looks like

```
char buf[16];
size_t i = 6;

sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
```

...and the compiler warns me that the 3rd argument is of type 'size_t' when the function is expecting an 'int'.

So I try telling it that it's going to get an unsigned int

```
sprintf(buf, "%u", i);
```

and now the compiler warns me that the 3rd argument is of type 'size_t' when the function is expecting an 'unsigned int'.

---

From what I read on other questions/answers regarding this issue, I cannot assume that size_t is an unsigned int, which explains the warning.

- So how can I re-write the line so the compiler is happy 
  (i.e. so the compiler is silent)?

---

**Edit:**

Before someone suggests it, I'm looking for a solution that actually addresses the slight possibility that something could go wrong.  So forcing a typecast by going

```
sprintf(buf, "%d", (int)i);
```

or

```
sprintf(buf, "%u", (unsigned int)i);
```

is undesirable.

Comment: thanks that apparently solves it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C99 and C11 require a `z` modifier:

```
sprintf(buf, "%zu", i);
```

If MS Visual Studio has to be accommodated too, life is probably harder (because it doesn't adhere to either the C99 or C11 standard).  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx), you need to use `I` instead of `z`.